# A lemma for the idea in the modern proof of Banach's Contraction Mapping Theorem

Tags: fixed-point-theorems, complete-spaces

> Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $T: X \rightarrow X$ a contraction mapping with a fixed point $w$. Suppose that $x_0 \in X$ and we define $x_n$ inductively by $x_{n+1}= Tx_n$. Show that $d(x_n,w) \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

$Proof:$
We observe that since $T$ is a contraction mapping on $X$, there exists a positive number $K<1$ with $d(Tx,Ty) \leq Kd(x,y)$ for all $x,y \in X$. Therefore we have that
$$d(x_n,w)=d(Tx_{n-1},Tw) \leq Kd(x_{n-1},w),$$
and we see that
$$d(x_n,w) \leq K^{n}d(x_0,w),$$
and hence $d(x_n,w) \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Could you please provide some feedback regarding the correctness of the above proof?

Comment: Looks good.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that in the first line, you should have the inequality $d(T x_{n-1}, Tw ) \leq K d(x_{n-1}, w)$, but besides this things seem correct.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I will correct the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Looks good to me!

Might want to double-check that the problem lets you assume the existence of a fixed point though.

Comment: Since the metric space is not given to be complete, that needs to be an assumption...

Comment: Mm, fair. I've only seen it on complete spaces so wanted to make sure that wasn't an accidental assumption.